# Using OWASP ZAP (and tools of the same purpose) on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, testing, owasp, security-testing

**I am currently planning to do some web application vulnerability testing on an EC2 server with OWASP ZAP.**

From my very quick google search, I found that AWS has stated that penetration testing services are allowed without approval (https://aws.amazon.com/security/penetration-testing/).

However, to double down, **I am wondering if anyone in the community has done this without issue.**

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I frequently ran ZAP scans in AWS while I was at Mozilla. They were of course all against apps that I was permitted to test.
You *should* be fine unless someone complains - if they do that then Amazon are likely to send you a warning and then disable your account if you dont reply with a good explanation, or if it keeps happenning of course.

Comment: Thanks for the info Simon! I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: I would have written the same exact answer if it wasn't listed.